# AS400 Printing to Windows Issue

Tags: windows, printing, ibm-midrange

I have looked all over for a resolution for this. I am attempting to send spool files from the AS400 to a Windows print queue. The document reaches the queue, except it's blank. A 1 page document is like 1kb in the queue and is blank of course. If I attempt a 13 page doc, it comes to about 95k or so. I am completely stumped. I did read somewhere that it could be because AS400 sends the data in RAW format, but I am not sure if that is the issue and I am also not sure how to change that even if it were the issue. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It would help to have more details of your configuration, are you using Host Print Transform with a remote writer or some other option to convert the queue to Windows format

Comment: 'AS400' is very old; searching for that will return antique results.  Try 'IBM i' or 'iSeries' for more modern search hits.  http://www-912.ibm.com/s_dir/SLKBase.nsf/0/ba0863cfa6463903862569c10078c903?OpenDocument  and  http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg246250.html

Comment: I appreciate the help man. I am using a host print transform with a remote writer. I followed this link: http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas1a559d25155ae5b708625725f0077c928 and like I said, it is reaching the Windows queue just fine, not not sure what data if any is being sent.

Comment: is the transform working correctly, try transforming to text and grabbing on the windows system

Comment: This is going to sound ridiculous, but how I transform it?

Comment: Is printing required or would converting to PDF solve the problem?  Also, what type of spooled file is this?  Check the printer device type attribute.  IT should be something like *SCS, *AFPDS, *IPDS, etc.